# Writing a Prolog format predicate

Tags: prolog

I have the database of rules and facts and I want to create the predicate `show(N)` witch shows the rule number `N`, with format/2 predicate.
Thank you.

```
% La base de connaissances
regle(1,cirres_ventraux,[deux_antennes,pas_de_paragnathes]).
regle(2,cirres_lateraux,[trois_antennes,pas_de_paragnathes]).
regle(3,machoire,[pas_de_paragnathes,pieds_birames,segment_bucal_apode]).
regle(4,pas_de_machoire,[paragnathes,pieds_birames,segment_bucal_avec_pieds]).
regle(5,nereis,[cirres_ventraux,machoire]).
regle(6,micronereis,[cirres_lateraux,machoire]).
regle(7,pas_de_paragnathes,[cirres_tentaculaires,branchies_spiralees,proboscis_complexe]).
regle(8,segment_bucal_apode,[parapodes_posterieurs]).
regle(9,machoire,[pieds_unirames,segment_bucal_invisible]).
% La base de faits
fait(cirres_tentaculaires).
fait(branchies_spiralees).
fait(parapodes_posterieurs).
```

Comment: The code is full of syntax errors. You do not explain how your predicates are supposed to encode rules and facts. You do not explain what you mean by "show" - print it, unify it with a variable, other? You also don't show how you tried to solve the problem so far.

Comment: Thanks you, i want to create the predicate show(N) to show the rule number N with format/2 predicate.